# how to do a left shift in Modelsim in order to built a booth multiplier

Tags: modelsim

I am writing a code for Booth Multiplier in ModelSim. Currently, I am implementing my code in a for loop. In the for loop there are `if..else` conditions that are checking 2 bits at a time of the multiplier. Here I need to do a left shift of the multiplicand but I am unable to do so.

How can we do a left shift in ModelSim since the shift operators don't work here?

Comment: Plz upload your code and add tag vhdl/verilog/etc. I cannot guess any problem with some text.

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL a two bit shift looks like this:

```
shifted := unshifted(unshifted'high-2 downto 0) & "00";
```